# How to remove escape characters from a JSON String

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I called a REST API with the following JSON string returned:

```
"{\"profile\":[{\"name\":\"city\",\"rowCount\":1,\"location\": ............
```

I tried to remove escape character with the following code before I deserialize it:

```
 jsonString = jsonString.Replace(@"\", " ");
```

But then when I deserialize it, it throws an `input string was not in a correct format`:

```
SearchRootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchRootObject>(jsonString);
```

The following is the complete code:

```
public static SearchRootObject obj()
    {
        String url = Glare.searchUrl;
        string jsonString = "";

        // Create the web request  
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

        // Get response  
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format.
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        jsonString = jsonString + readStream.ReadToEnd();
        jsonString = jsonString.Replace(@"\", " ");

        // A C# object representation of deserialized JSON string 
        SearchRootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchRootObject>(jsonString);
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post a complete example that includes the exact JSON you're having trouble with and the class you're attempting to deserialize to? Also, why are you trying to remove the "\" character?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, I solved this problem, and I posted the solution as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After switching to use `JavaScriptSerializer()` to deserialize JSON string , I realized that I have an `int` type `property` in my object for a decimal value in the JSON string. I changed `int` to `double`, and this solved my problem. Both `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>` and `JavaScriptSerializer()` handle escape character. There's no need to remove escape character. 
I replaced the following codes:

```
jsonString = jsonString.Replace(@"\", " ");        
SearchRootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchRootObject>(jsonString);
return obj;
```

With:

```
return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<SearchObj.RootObject>(jsonString);
```