# once I serializer array i have this json format :\" before every key there is a way to ignore it?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
var query = (from item in UserDevices
                         select new Device
                         {
                             Device_SN= item.Device_SN,
                             Device_ID= item.Device_ID
                         }).ToList();
```

The response I get

```
"{"GetUserDevicesResult":"[{\"Device_ID\":1,\"Device_SN\":\"1504111\",\"User_Devices\":[]}"}"
```

Is there is a way to remove the `\` and not doing manipulations of replace?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question:

[How to remove escape characters from a JSON String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979508/how-to-remove-escape-characters-from-a-json-string)

I think you have serialization issue similar to the problem described above.

Please note that JSON inherits JS notation when representing special characters and punctuations, thus the escape sequence rule also applies on .json file.

If you want to deserialize JSON data without "\" escape sequence character in C#, call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonstringdata)`.

CMIIW.